# Incorrect return value when using ExecuteNonQuery()

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I have a C# program I'm writing which interacts with SQL Server.  I had foolishly hard-coded the query strings into the C# program, and wanted to instead turn those into Stored Procedures on the server.

For some reason, one particular INSERT statement (that was working fine!) no longer works and I can't figure out why.  I've even run a SQL Profiler Trace, and it shows that the statement is perfectly formed!  Maybe someone can tell me what I'm doing wrong.

STORED PROCEDURE:
This SP just takes a bunch of parameters and inserts them into a table.  Very simple.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_InsertNewChangeRequest]

@Requester INT,
@ChangeCreationDate DATETIME,
@ChangeName VARCHAR(200),
@ChangeDescription VARCHAR(1000),
@LastModifiedDate DATETIME,
@LastModifiedBy INT,
@AffectedArea INT,
@ImplementationPlan VARCHAR(MAX),
@BackoutPlan VARCHAR(MAX),
@RiskLevel TINYINT,
@ApprovalRequired BIT,
@IsApproved BIT
AS
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;

INSERT INTO dbo.ChangeRequests(Requester, ChangeCreationDate, ChangeName, ChangeDescription, 
            LastModifiedDate, LastModifiedBy, AffectedArea, ImplementationPlan, BackoutPlan, 
            RiskLevel, ApprovalRequired, IsApproved)
VALUES (@Requester, @ChangeCreationDate, @ChangeName, @ChangeDescription,
            @LastModifiedDate, @LastModifiedBy, @AffectedArea, @ImplementationPlan, @BackoutPlan,
            @RiskLevel, @ApprovalRequired, @IsApproved) 
END
```

My code in C# simply preps the SP parameters then calls a nonquery:

```
public int InsertNewChange(int RequesterID, DateTime CreationDate, string ChangeName,
        string ChangeDescription, DateTime LastModifiedDate, 
        int AffectedAreaID, string ImplementationPlan, string BackoutPlan,
        int RiskLevel, int ApprovalRequired, int IsApproved)
    {
        int retval = 0;

        // Create a command whose name is the stored procedure for inserts
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("usp_InsertNewChangeRequest", scConnection);
        command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

        // add the parameters to the stored procedure
        command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Requester", RequesterID));
        command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@ChangeCreationDate", CreationDate));
        command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@ChangeName", ChangeName));
        command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@ChangeDescription", ChangeDescription));
        command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@LastModifiedDate", LastModifiedDate));
        command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@LastModifiedBy", RequesterID));
        command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@AffectedArea", AffectedAreaID));
        command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@ImplementationPlan", ImplementationPlan));
        command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@BackoutPlan", BackoutPlan));
        command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@RiskLevel", RiskLevel));
        command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@ApprovalRequired", ApprovalRequired));
        command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@IsApproved", IsApproved));

        retval = command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        return retval;
    }
```

I'm constantly getting a -1 return value, whereas before, when I had the SQL text spelled out entirely in C#, I would get a 1, for the 1 row inserted.

Infuriatingly, I don't see any error in SQL Profiler when doing a trace.  It shows the statement passed, and it looks completely fine!  When I cut and paste it into Management Studio and run it myself by hand, it works fine.

```
    exec usp_InsertNewChangeRequest @Requester=4,@ChangeCreationDate='2012-05-16 17:55:45',@ChangeName='test name',@ChangeDescription='test description',@LastModifiedDate='2012-05-16 17:56:01.937',@LastModifiedBy=4,@AffectedArea=2,@ImplementationPlan='test implem',@BackoutPlan='test backout',@RiskLevel=1,@ApprovalRequired=0,@IsApproved=0
```

Does anyone know why this would be happening to me?  MANY THANKS!

Comment: try adding dbo. to the following line SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("dbo.usp_InsertNewChangeRequest", scConnection);

Comment: @atbebtg: No...the stored procedure runs just fine without the dbo.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Because you turned it off:

```
SET NOCOUNT ON;
```

Comment: +1: Yep. `SET NOCOUNT ON;` will prevent the number of affected rows from being counted and returned. @user1399660: Change your `ON` to `OFF` or remove the statement from your stored procedure.

Comment: I think I would rather change the stored procedure to use @@rowcount and output the row count using an output param, or use try/catch and return the appropriate status depending on success or failure. The problem with relying on NOCOUNT being OFF is hat setting it on is a widely publicized best practice, and the stored procedure could be changed down the road by a cleanup crew who has absolutely no way to know you're relying on the OFF behavior.

Comment: Thank you everyone.  Aaron, I have control of this particular database, but I will leave a comment in the code mentioning that the program relies on SET NOCOUNT OFF.

Comment: Here is the better question to ask. If he ran the SP in Management Studio, why did it return the correct count when SET NOCOUNT ON was being used in that SP? What did that setting have to do with the .NET code? Manually executing the SP works but not with the SqlCommand?

Comment: @AndrewFinnell Yep, pretty much.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using `@@RowCount;` instead of relying on the row count being returned if it's a `INSERT, UPDATE, or DELETE`.

It appears many suggestions around SP is to use `@@RowCount` and `SET NOCOUNT ON;`

Comment: @asawyer Doesn't that return the last identity value that was generated? He wants the number of rows effected not the identity value.