# ExecuteNonQuery not returning row affected count for correct SQL query

Tags: c#, sql, ms-access

Although there are many questions asked for ExecuteNonQuery, this case is a little different. I have a SQL query which is working fine when executed in MS Access

[image]

but when I call the same like the following:

```
updateStatement = "UPDATE Claims_Data SET Notes='DOS (Professional), Not In System',Visit='256', Denial_Reason='Not In System', Paid_Amt='0', Check_Num='', Check_Date=''  WHERE Subscriber_ID='4562' AND (DOS LIKE '*9/15/2014*' OR DOS LIKE '*09/15/2014*') AND CPT='99214'  AND Provider='R,P MD'"

        updateCommand = new OleDbCommand(updateStatement, cn);

        cn.Open();

        try
        {
            int count = updateCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        catch (OleDbException ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            cn.Close();
        }
```

The value of 'count' also comes 0, I have checked the connection property as well. Any help?

Comment: Can you also post the full query? Does it actually perform the operation correctly?

Comment: I don't see why an "insertStatement" would return something?

Comment: @Hypenate: INSERT normally returns the number of rows it inserted.

Comment: I agree with @YuriyGalanter.  Make sure you update is actually updating the records.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: What is NOCOUNT set to?  http://stackoverflow.com/a/10627387/2394945

Comment: *IT'S OLEDEB Connection to MS ACCESS. What NOCOUNT?* @student - does that query finds record to update correctly when u run it by itself? Those WHERE conditions looks shady. E.g. why do you do LIKE comparassing on dates?